# Access ArrayBuffer request payload in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arraybuffer

```
app.post("/arraybuffer/:filename", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.params.filename);
}
```

I have a nodejs server which receives an `ArrayBuffer` posted to it from the client side using [xhr.send](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-string).

- I can see the `ArrayBuffer` data under Request payload in `POST` request by using chrome dev tools under the network tab!

But when I `console.log(req.body)`, I get `{}`. 
I also tried `console.log(new Uint8Array(req.body));` - similar result - `Uint8Array {}`

By the way, `console.log(req.params.filename);` is working fine.

Need help, thanks.

(P.S. - I have the following in my app.js at the top, so its not a json parsing issue)

```
app.use(bodyparser.json({limit: "15mb"}));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body don't see anything about ArrayBuffers...

Comment: It looks like `bodyparser` doesn't handle binary data so you will either have to find some middleware that does or just read the actual http post data yourself.

Comment: This worked - app.use(bodyparser.raw({type: "application/octet-stream"})); and insert header: application/octet-stream on the client-side!